# how to determine if system is matched in system

Tags: rf

I'm concerned about matching. If you look at the pictures, there is a certain tracewidth optimized for 50 ohm that is then changed to fit the pad of the rf component. How would I measure the amount of reflection in an already built system?

Situations: The RF board is already built, there is another component that generates the rf signal on the other side of the board, making the attachment of an sma connector to hook up a network analyzer not so likely. Even if it wasn't there, the trace is far from the board edge (maybe a right angle sma connector and unloading the rf generator?).

Additionally, it would be nice to test this for every board that comes through production (making attaching components not an option). Is there a way to test it with an rf probe (just a cable that you touch the tip of the cable to the trace) or some other method to ensure accurate matching?

[image: much bright very rf]
[image: why is the real world so hard?]

Comment: What's your operating frequency?

Comment: @ThePhoton above 2 ghz.

Comment: With a TDR or VNA?

Comment: 1 million tera hertz is above 2GHz. BTW that's capital G, capital H and not "ghz". If you are worried about a small section of trace nipping in a bit then how worried are you about the trace not appearing to be terminated in a matched load.

Comment: @Andyaka I was going to make a point about that via. I assume you mean that one?

Comment: @Asmyldof No the other one LOL. I have no idea what via you mean and as for the Q, i'm not sure the questioner sees the problem of terminations if he thinks a tiny bit of track thinned down is a problem.

Comment: @Andyaka Ah, hang on, it's not a via. :-)

Comment: @SomeHardwareGuy We have a VNA, but if there's a solution with TDR, we can switch to that. A VNA would work well, but the issue is how to measure the system without influencing it. If we added a sma connector to one of the traces, we would have to place it just right to not have inadvertant stubs coming out the back, causing an error in measurement. Additionally, we would be sending back RF to some of the components-not ideal.

Comment: @LegenDiary, the operating frequency absolutely does matter. If you were working at 50 MHz, I would recommend to  just put a scope probe on it (or just not worry about it). If you were working at 25 GHz I would tell you you need to make a test coupon with appropriate connector footprints. At 2 GHz I think I have a few suggestions which I will write up when I have a bit more time.

Comment: @ThePhoton thank you for your reply. You mentioned for 25 GHz a test coupon. I assume that means building a small replica board with the same trace layout to make it easy to add connectors to test reflection with the VNA. I think that's the route we should go in the future. Have any suggestions for an already built board?

Comment: @LegenDiary, what is the VSWR spec of the chip providing the termination? I'll bet it's way worse than the effects from the pcb layout.

Comment: @ThePhoton The return loss is 17 dB which is 1.33 VSWR. My intent with the question was to find more testing techniques that allow me to gain insight into the board, and whether there is a way to do it without explicitly build a test coupon. With that information I could determine if there is a basic issue with the width of the traces or if the issue lies in the part. You have any more ideas for higher frequencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some things to consider.

1. The wavelength at 2 GHz is about 150 mm in vacuum, maybe 75 mm in FR4. Your discontinuity is much much shorter than that so isn't likely to have much effect on the signal.
2. At 2 GHz, measuring with the chip in place, no matter what technique you use, you're not going to be able to tell the difference between a reflection caused by your PCB layout and a reflection caused by the chip termination and package.
3. The track narrowing is producing an inductive parasitic. The nearby top-layer ground is producing a capacitive parastic. You shouldn't just be worried about the track narrowing. If you're lucky (or design for it to begin with) the two effects might balance each other out.
4. If you still want to make a measurement, you have a few options:

   A. Active oscilloscope probes are nowadays available up to your frequency and beyond. Assuming you can make your system generate a single-frequency excitation, you could place the probe at different points along the line and estimate the VSWR.

   B. If you can't spend money on a GHz active probe, a 500-ohm resitive probe should be able to measure signals on your trace adequately. These have been available for many years. They do produce a small discontinuity on the line, and produce 10:1 attenuation of the signal delivered to the 'scope, so they're not necessarily ideal.

   C. Companies like Cascade make coplanar microprobes that might be able to contact your trace and the surrounding ground planes. If you do this with the source and load chips in place, it will produce a substantial discontinuity (essentially an un-matched tee). If you connect the microprobe in place of the source IC you should be able to do a nice TDR and see the discontinuities in your whole setup (traces, via, and termination).

Comment: add in the higher frequency ideas and I'll accept the answer. If you can measure it at 25 Ghz and add in tuning dots, you should be able to minimize the VSWR for both the trace and the component.

Comment: @LegenDiary, what I said before was: " at 25 GHz I would tell you you need to make a test coupon with appropriate connector footprints. At 2 GHz I think I have a few suggestions which I will write up when I have a bit more time." My suggestions for testing at 2 GHz are already included in my answer.

Comment: Test coupons is what I was referring to. It's in enough places now so someone should be able to find it